# File acls (setfacl) not working how I would expect them to

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, sftp, acl

I have a basic SFTP server setup using [`OpenSSH`](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/sftp.1). To setup the SFTP server, I followed these steps:

**Step 1:** I installed the OpenSSH package.

`sudo apt-get install openssh-server -y`

**Step 2:** Created separate group for SFTP users.

`sudo groupadd sftpaccess`

**Step 3:** I edited the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file by finding `Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server` and commnting it out. After that I went to the very bottom of the file and added this:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match group ftpaccess
ChrootDirectory %h
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

**Step 4:** Restarted the sshd service.

`sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart`

**Step 5:** Added User with sftpaccess group and create password

```
useradd -s /bin/bash -m -U -G sftpaccess sftp-alex
passwd sftp-alex
```

**Step 6:** Create and Modify user directory.

```
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/users/sftp-alex/www
sudo chown root:root /mnt/users/sftp-alex
sudo chown root:sftpaccess /mnt/users/sftp-alex/www
```

**My goal (The thing that is stumping me):**

1. I want to create a directory here (`/mnt/www`) for something like a user share and then bind that to `/mnt/users/sftp-alex/www` so it would look something like this:

   - **Making the user share:** `mkdir /mnt/www`
   - **Binding share to users** `mount --bind /mnt/www /mnt/users/sftp-alex/www`
2. The next thing in this process is to create a sharing system/permissions system. My thought on how to do this is pretty straightforward in execution. I want to create two groups, one called **`sftp_read_write`** and the other one called **`sftp_read`** now if you can't already tell where I am going with this then let me explain. I am going to be using `setfacl` to add acls to files and folders. My thought was something like this `setfacl -Rm g:sftp_read_write:rwX,g:sftp_read:rX /mnt/www`. Now this is all great and all but it does not work I can **read** and **write** whether I am in **`sftp_read_write`** or **`sftp_read`** or **`sftpaccess`**

I really need help figuring this out I have gotten a setup like this to work before, which was about a year ago but I have forgotten all of the commands/permissions which is why I am asking this question.

**Output of getfacl**

```
# file: www
# owner: root
# group: sftpaccess
user::---
group::---
group:sftp_read:r-x
group:sftp_read_write:rwx
mask::rwx
other::---
```

**File trying to eddit**

```
# file: Test.txt
# owner: sftp-alex
# group: sftp-alex
user::rw-
group::rw-
other::r--
```

**Note:** I can edit this file wheather I am in the **`sftp_read`** or the **`sftp_read_write`** which should not be the case I should only be able to read and write if I am in the **`sftp_read_write`**.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: use `getfacl /mnt/www`, what's the result?

Comment: @FarazX I just edited the question with the output of `getfacl /mnt/www`

Comment: So that's working OK, `getfacl` the file you're trying to edit.

Comment: @FarazX I just edited the question again with the output of `getfacl /mnt/www/Test.txt`. Make sure that you read the note underneath.

Comment: Run your command: `setfacl -Rm g:sftp_read_write:rwX,g:sftp_read:rX /mnt/www` again. What happens??

Comment: ACL is not set on your file!

Comment: @FarazX That did not work I can still read and write no matter what group I am in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43600/discussion-between-farazx-and-alex).